# how to have an insert inside another insert in node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this post where I perform an insert and I need to get the id to be able to use it in another insert.

```
router.post('/save_card', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
      const page = req.body.page;
      const container_card = req.body.container_card;


      mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO pages (name_page) VALUES (?)', [page],
           (err, results, fields) => {
                if (err) throw err;
        
                container_card.forEach(card => {
                    mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO cards (id_page, container_card) VALUES (?,?)', [results.insertId, card],
                        (err, rows, fields) => {
                              if (err) throw err;
                              res.json({
                                        message: 'Card created successfully',
                              });

                        });
                });

          });
});
```

it works but it gives me an error

C:\Users\lcardemi\Desktop\PROYECTO CARD 3.0\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

Execute `INSERT INTO pages (name_page) VALUES (?)` providing `[page]` as a parameter.

Step 2.

Execute `INSERT INTO cards (id_page, container_card) SELECT id, ? FROM pages WHERE name_page = ?` providing `[card, page]` as parameters. Applicable only when `pages.name_page` is defined as unique.

Alternatively execute `INSERT INTO cards (id_page, container_card) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?)` providing `[card]` as parameter. But you must execute this query in the same connection, and you must guarantee that none query was executed between steps 1 and 2, including hidden statements sent by the connector.

Comment: it works but it keeps throwing me the same error

Comment: @user289418 This error is not relative to MySQL, it is clear JScript code error. I cannot help you with it - I don't use JScript.